# Access ftp service via other docker container

Tags: docker, ftp, docker-compose, docker-network

I have a Golang app, and it is supposed to connect to a FTP Server.

Now, both Golang app and FTP Server is dockerized, but I don't know how to connect to FTP server from Golang app

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  myappgo:
    image: myappgo:exp
    volumes:
      - ./volume:/go
    networks:
      myappgo_network:
    env_file:
      - test.env

  ftpd-server:
    container_name: ftpd-server
    image: stilliard/pure-ftpd:hardened
    ports:
      - "21:21"
      - "30000-30009:30000-30000"
    environment:
      PUBLICHOST: "localhost"
      FTP_USER_NAME: "test"
      FTP_USER_PASS: "test"
      FTP_USER_HOME: "/home/test"
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      myappgo_network:

networks:
  myappgo_network:
```

When I run docker compose, all services are up.

I could get IP of ftp container with:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' ftpd-server
```

And then, I installed a ftp client for alpine in my golang container, lftp:

```
docker exec -it my_app_go sh
apk add lftp
lftp -d ftp://test:test@172.19.0.2 # -d for debug
lftp test@172.19.0.2:~> ls
---- Connecting to 172.19.0.2 (172.19.0.2) port 21
`ls' at 0 [Connecting...]
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Is the ports line ok?
```- "30000-30009:30000-30000"````
Last 30000 should be 30009, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First simplify your `dockerfile`

```
version: '3'  # i assume you can migrate to version 3, yes?
services:
  myappgo:
    image: myappgo:exp
    volumes:
      - ./volume:/go
    env_file:
      - test.env
  ftpd-server:
    image: stilliard/pure-ftpd:hardened
    environment:
      PUBLICHOST: "0.0.0.0"
      FTP_USER_NAME: "test"
      FTP_USER_PASS: "test"
      FTP_USER_HOME: "/home/test"
    restart: on-failure
```

Second, default network is created by `docker-compose`; no need to do it explicitly. All services get connected to it under their names, so you access them not by `ip` but by name like `ftpd-server`

Third, you dont need to expose your ports if you access them from inside. If you need to access them from outside, then you expose.

Next, launch ftp with binding to `0.0.0.0` - binding any tcp service to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` makes it accessable only locally.

Last, use service names to connect. Forget about `ip` addresses and `docker inspect`. You connection from `myappgo` to ftp will look like `ftp://ftpd-server/foo/bar`

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked. I posted another related question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54324387/connecting-ftp-container-works-with-docker-compose-and-not-with-docker-run

Comment: @grapes hi, can you have a quick look at my containerised ftp-server pls?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64438942/nodejs-application-stops-working-when-containerised?noredirect=1#comment113946483_64438942

Comment: `PUBLICHOST` set to `0.0.0.0` results in FTP with no files for me, set to real host hostname works well.

Answer (score 5):

At least, you need 21/TCP for commands and 20/TCP for data on ftp-server:

```
ports:
  - "21:21"
  - "20:20"
  - "30000-30009:30000-30009"
```

I changed your compose-file a little bit:

```
version: '2'

services:
  myappgo:
    image: alpine:3.8
    tty: true
    networks:
      swarm_default:

  ftpd-server:
    container_name: ftpd-server
    image: stilliard/pure-ftpd:hardened
    ports:
      - "21:21"
      - "20:20"
      - "30000-30009:30000-30009"
    environment:
      PUBLICHOST: "localhost"
      FTP_USER_NAME: "test"
      FTP_USER_PASS: "test"
      FTP_USER_HOME: "/home/test"
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      swarm_default:

networks:
  swarm_default:
```

Then I created on ftp-server file `/home/test/1` and I can see it from mygoapp-container:

```
/ # lftp ftp://test:test@172.19.0.2
lftp test@172.19.0.2:/> dir
-rw-r--r--    1 0          0                   0 Jan 22 14:18 1
```

Comment: hi, can you have a quick look at my containerised ftp-server pls?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64438942/nodejs-application-stops-working-when-containerised?noredirect=1#comment113946483_64438942