# Connecting FTP container works with docker-compose and not with docker run

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need to connect FTP server from my_go_app container.
When I do it from it from docker compose, I can do it with:

```
apk add lftp
lftp -d ftp://julien:test@ftpd-server
```

and it connects well

but when I try to run my container via `docker run`, I cannot connect anymore to FTP server

Here the command I use:

```
docker run --name my_go_app --rm -v volume:/go my_go_app:exp --network=my_go_app_network --env-file ./test.env
```

Here is the working docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  my_go_app:
    image: my_go_app:exp
    volumes:
      - ./volume:/go
    networks:
      my_go_app_network:
    env_file:
      - test.env

  ftpd-server:
    container_name: ftpd-server
    image: stilliard/pure-ftpd:hardened
    ports:
      - "21:21"
      - "30000-30009:30000-30000"
    environment:
      PUBLICHOST: "0.0.0.0"
      FTP_USER_NAME: "julien"
      FTP_USER_PASS: "test"
      FTP_USER_HOME: "/home/www/julien"
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      my_go_app_network:

networks:
  my_go_app_network:
    external: true
```

EDIT:

I added the network as external and created it manually with:

```
 docker network create my_go_app_network
```

Now it appears that my_go_app is part of the default network:

```
my_go_app git:(tests) ✗ docker inspect my_go_app -f "{{json .NetworkSettings.Networks }}"         
{"bridge":{"IPAMConfig":null,"Links":null,"Aliases":null,"NetworkID":"62b2dff15ff00d5cd56c966cc562b8013d06f18750e3986db530fbb4dc4cfba7","EndpointID":"6d0a81a83cdf639ff13635f0a38eeb962075cd729181b7c60fadd43446e13607","Gateway":"172.17.0.1","IPAddress":"172.17.0.2","IPPrefixLen":16,"IPv6Gateway":"","GlobalIPv6Address":"","GlobalIPv6PrefixLen":0,"MacAddress":"02:42:ac:11:00:02","DriverOpts":null}}


➜  my_go_app git:(tests) ✗ docker network ls
  NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
  62b2dff15ff0        bridge              bridge              local
  f33ab34dd91d        host                host                local
  ee2d604d6604        none                null                local
  61a661c82262        my_go_app_network      bridge              local
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: I'm sorry if this is stating the obvious, but have you double-checked (with `docker ps`) that both containers are up and running as expected? Also, it's worth checking what is in each container's log - there are often useful clues there.

Comment: yes both container are up, and nothing wrong in the logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your network `my_go_app_network` should be declared as "external", otherwise compose will create a network called "*project_name*_my_go_app_network". Therefore your go app was not in the same network with the ftp server.

(I guess you have created `my_go_app_network` manually so your `docker run` did not throw any network not found error.)

EDIT

You put the arguments in the wrong order. Image name has to be the last one, otherwise they are considered as "commands" for the container. Try

`docker run --name my_go_app --rm -v volume:/go  --network=my_go_app_network --env-file ./test.env my_go_app:exp`

Comment: Yes, they are not in the same network, but can't figure out why. I created a network manually and used it as external in docker compose, but when I execute docker run, it stills run in the default network, even if I use --network=my_go_app_network. Don't know why

Comment: yep, that was the problem. Is there any additional restrictions about order ? any docs that mention it ?

Comment: you can use `docker run --help` which gives you `docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]`

Comment: @Siyuhi, can you have a quick look at my containerised ftp-server pls?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64438942/nodejs-application-stops-working-when-containerised?noredirect=1#comment113946483_64438942